# how to fix my keyboad

Tags: keyboard

I was working with my laptop suddenly the some problems happen for my keyboard. the

<kbd>J</kbd> switch to <kbd>1</kbd>

<kbd>K</kbd> switch to <kbd>2</kbd>

<kbd>L</kbd> switch to <kbd>3</kbd>

<kbd>U</kbd> switch to <kbd>4</kbd>

<kbd>I</kbd> switch to <kbd>5</kbd>

and ...

How can I fix this? and If you, know what do you guess about the reason of this problem?

Ps : I have two keyboard and I am using that one which exclude from the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have pressed `Num Lock` key by mistake.

Just press it one more time, and Bingo!